# How do i use service account in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am using the office 365 connector as part of my workflow in the azure logic apps to listen to calendar events.  Right now i am receiving notifications on the events only to the account i linked. I have a requirement to listen to more than one account. Say for ex: I want to receive event notifications from a set of users i want. I have a service account which has impersonation privileges. I mapped this service account in the connector. But i dont see any events flowing from other user accounts. My question, is it really possible to achieve this? If yes, how?

Comment: Have you looked into using Microsoft Graph API instead?

Comment: I initially used Microsoft graph and Azure functions. But since java support for Azure functions  is still in preview we dont want to use it. Logic Apps were advertised for this purpose. But i cant really link multiple accounts to the logic apps.